# Contradictory results of the integral of an odd function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I got two contradictory results for the integral of an odd function. I believe I made some kind of mistake but I can't figure it out.

$f(x)$ is an odd function, which means $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for any $x$. $F(x)$ is an integral of $f(x)$. So $F(x) = \int f(x) dx$.

But the integral can be calculated like this.

$$  \int f(x) dx = \int f(-y) d(-y) \,\,(y=-x) \\
= -\int f(y) \frac{d(-y)}{dy} dy \\
= \int f(y) dy \\
=F(y) \\
=F(-x)$$

$\int f(x) dx = F(x)$ and $\int f(x) dx = F(-x)$. It's quite weird. Why is this happening?

Comment: The integral of an odd function is even (i.e. $F(x) = F(-x)$, this is what you have shown. There is nothing contradictory here. Take the derivative of $F(-x)$ and $F(x)$ and compare the result, keeping in mind that $f(x)$ is odd.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider that

$$f(x)=x \implies \int x dx = \frac12 x^2 +c$$

and also note that

$$f(x)=f(-x)\implies f'(x)=-1\cdot f'(-x)$$